# Python 3.4 pip install wheel fails on Yosemite - "not a supported wheel on this platform"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip, osx-yosemite

I've been trying to install numpy, pysci etc on a MacBook Pro with Yosemite and fresh installation of ActiveState Python 3.4. I have tried many wheel files and they all fail with "not a supported wheel on this platform". For example, using the latest wheel file for Python 3.4 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy:

```
...$ sudo pip3 install numpy-1.9.1-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl

numpy-1.9.1-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I traced my way through wheel.py, req.py and pep425tags.py to try to understand why it failed.
In pep425tags.py it uses

```
distutils.util.get_platform().replace('.', '_').replace('-', '_')
```

which, presumably, is then compared to tags in the filename of the wheel file.

Since I have upgraded to Yosemite, I was expecting that my computer would return something like: "macosx_10_10_intel" or "macosx_10_10_x86_64" - but instead it returns "macosx_10_6_x86_64"

```
>>> import distutils.util
>>> distutils.util.get_platform().replace('.', '_').replace('-', '_')
'macosx_10_6_x86_64'
>>>
```

Am I correct that Yosemite is apparently reporting that it is Snow Leopard? Or is Python 3.4 getting it wrong? Is this my problem with wheel files? If so, is there a fix?

---

Updating to Python 3.4.2 corrected the problem and I was able to install the numpy wheel file.
Please note however, that distutils.util.get_platform() still reports "macosx_10_6_intel" but that does not affect the installation.

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  5 2014, 20:42:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import distutils.util
>>> distutils.util.get_platform().replace('.', '_').replace('-', '_')
'macosx_10_6_intel'
```

Comment: I get `'macosx_10_10_x86_64'` on my Yosemite 10.10 install. Are you sure you are using this with Python 3.4?

Comment: You can just set the `_PYTHON_HOST_PLATFORM` environment variable to override.

Comment: Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
    Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
    >>> import distutils.util
    >>> distutils.util.get_platform().replace('.', '_').replace('-', '_')
    'macosx_10_6_x86_64'
    >>>

Comment: Is the `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` environment variable set?

Comment: Thank you Martijn. Sorry I'm a bit new - where would I do that? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: In the shell, use `echo $MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`. Or in Python, look at `os.environ.get('MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET ')`.

Comment: I unset MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

    /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist shows:
            <key>ProductUserVisibleVersion</key>
            <string>10.10.1</string>
            <key>ProductVersion</key>
            <string>10.10.1</string>

Both echo $MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET and os.environ.get('MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET ')
return empty strings.

But Python still reports: 'macosx_10_6_x86_64'

Comment: What does `import _osx_support; print(_osx_support._get_system_version())` produce?

Comment: >>> _osx_support._get_system_version():    
'10.10'

Comment: Next command: `import distutils; import _osx_support; _osx_support.get_platform_osx(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_vars(), osname, release, machine)`.

Comment: >>> _osx_support.get_platform_osx(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_vars(), osname, release, machine)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    _osx_support.get_platform_osx(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_vars(), osname, release, machine)
NameError: name 'osname' is not defined

Comment: Oops, sorry, missing line:  `import os; osname, host, release, version, machine = os.uname()`, then try again.

Comment: ('macosx', '10.6', 'x86_64')

Comment: Ah, I think I am on to something; there was a [recent change](https://hg.python.org/cpython/diff/14198fda1c70/Lib/_osx_support.py) to that file for Yosemite. You have 3.4.1, I have 3.4.2.

Comment: sorry for leading you on this goose chase, I wasn't aware of the changes made to the platform detection here; I was looking at the 3.4.2 codebase and missed that there were some crucial changes made here in the latest release.

Comment: So the solution is to move to Python 3.4.2?

Comment: Yes, or manually apply the patches from the bug report. However, that would still require a recompilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take into account that `distutils.util.get_platform()` returns the *minimal version* on which the binary will run:

> For Mac OS X systems the OS version reflects the minimal version on which
>      binaries will run (that is, the value of `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`
>      during the build of Python), **not the OS version of the current system.**

*Emphasis mine*. That said, for Python 3.4 you can reasonably expect the value to be 10.10 if you built Python on that platform.

For Python to handle `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to work correctly throughout, you need to upgrade to Python 3.4.2; 3.4.1 is not ready for Mac OS X 10.10 or higher. See issue [#21811](http://bugs.python.org/issue21811):

> There are a number of places within the cpython code base where decisions are made based on either the running system version or the OS X ABI (e.g. the value of MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET) that the interpreter was built with or is being built with.  Most of the current tests do string comparisons of these values which will not work properly with a two-digit version number ('10.10' < '10.9' --> True).

3.4.2 includes the required fixes. The same applies to Python 2.7 up to version 2.7.7; if you see this same problem in Python 2.7 upgrade to 2.7.8 or up.

Without the fixes, `intel` is mixed up with `x86_64`, as is the case with your setup:

> 1. When running current 3.4.1 and 2.7.7 binary installers on 10.10, building C extension modules will likely result in an incorrect universal platform name, for example, "x86_64" instead of "intel", and that could affect extension module file names and wheel or egg names.

For reference, on my OS X 10.10 system, on Python 3.4.2 the result of `get_platform()` is:

```
>>> import distutils.util
>>> distutils.util.get_platform()
'macosx-10.10-x86_64'
```

and for Python 2.7.8 I get:

```
>>> import distutils.util
>>> distutils.util.get_platform()
'macosx-10.4-x86_64'
```

Comment: since both 3.4.2 and 2.7.8 have the fix, why is that `get_platform()` returns a different tag? shouldn't they be the same if it is the minimum required target platform?

Comment: @dashesy: the minimum is set by the configuration script (recorded in the Makefile), and differs per Python version.